# How to change Rootview controller from a different module?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have split my project into a number of feature modules. I need to show login screen first and on logging in assign my tabbar controller as rootview. Then on logging out reassign my login screen as rootview. If my login feature and tabbar controllers are in different modules, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make a public function to set the `rootViewController` in the main module and call it from any module you like. Here's the function you need to add to your main module:

```
public func setRootViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewController
}
```